# How to pass the radio button id in the anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the list of records like this

```
o 1 xxx yyy
o 2 xxx yyy
o 3 xxx yyy
```

if i click the first record radio bhutton, the value of 1 pass to anchor tag

```
    <?php foreach($model as $result) { ?>
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="pol_id" value="<?=$result['id']?>" />
                <?=$result['name']?>
            </td>
            <td><?=$result['country']?></td>
            <td><?=$result['state']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="update?id=<?=$result['id']?>">Edit
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: You will need javascript to do that.

Comment: Please show your rendered HTML, PHP is irrelevant here, and makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use javascript for it.

**jQuery Code:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function(){
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
    $('a').attr('href', 'update?id='+$(this).val()); // better if you add an id to anchor & then $('a#idofAnchor')
});

});</script>
```

Comment: if it is more action on single radio butto means hoe can i give the link...
For example: Selecting one radio button of the record , i have to perform Edit/Delete/View ....

Comment: Post a question related to that & share url here if need assistance on that.

Comment: I got the answer by giving the id of the Edit/ Delete/ View